# iOS Allow UITableViewCell swipe deletion and rearrangeable cells simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe

In order to enable rearrangeable (moveable) cells in my `UITableView`, I must set `table.isEditing` to `true` and implement the following delegate methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
```

I also implement the following delegate methods to hide the default table-editing UI:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    return .none
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

I would also like to swipe-delete the cells in this table. I've tried using both the `tableView(_:editActionsForRowAt:)` approach and the new iOS 11 `tableView(_:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)` but neither work while `table.isEditing = true`. The only other relevant table delegate method I use is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
```

which returns `true` for all cells.

Is there a way to enable both of these UITableView features simultaneously? It looks possible as this is exactly how the table queue in the Apple Music app works:

[image]

Comment: Did you try returning `.delete` instead of `.none`?

Comment: That brings back the "-" delete button on the left side of the cell and still does not let me swipe the cell

Comment: @EvanKaminsky did you come up with a solution? It's not just the music app where Apple has implemented this pattern. They've used it in other native apps as well. I've been researching this for a couple of days now.

Comment: I eventually decided to implement my own table cell drag mechanism using my own 'hamburger' icon and a UILongPressGesture with a minimumPressDuration of 0. I provided some of that code's structure in a different StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55860124/swift-programmatically-launch-a-uilongpressgesture